# Integration of the error function, $\text{erf}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

I encountered the following the definite integrals.

When
$$
\text{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int\limits_0^x e^{-t^2} \, dt
$$

$$
I_1 = \int\limits_0^\infty \left(1 - \text{erf}\left(\frac{t - m}{s}\right)\right) \, dt 
= m\left(1 + \text{erf}\left(\frac{m}{s}\right)\right) + \frac{s}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left(-\left(\frac{m}{s}\right)^2\right) \quad \text{if} \quad s > 0.
$$

When $s_1 > 0$, $s_2 > 0$, what is $I_2$?
$$
I_2 = \int\limits_0^\infty \left(1 - \text{erf}\left(\frac{t - m_1}{s_1}\right)\right)\left(1 - \text{erf}\left(\frac{t - m_2}{s_2}\right)\right) \, dt
$$

Comment: To simplify your question, I would eliminate the known cross terms and simply ask about $$\int\limits_0^\infty {\rm erf}\left( \frac{t-m_1}{s_1}\right) {\rm erf}\left( \frac{t-m_2}{s_2}\right) \ dt$$  Alas, though, I don't know how to integrate the product of error functions.

Comment: The error function $\text{erf}(x)$ is an increasing function and $\text{erf}(\infty) = 1$.
Therefore, 
$$
\int_0^\infty \text{erf}\left(\frac{t - m_1}{s_1}\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{t - m_2}{s_2}\right) \, dt = \infty
$$
However, $I_2$ converges.